# Fill DataTable with many SQL Tables and add a new column to know from which table

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable

I am using vb.net and I need to query 4 SQL Tables and write the output to a DataTable. 
So I am doing this (example with 2 Tables), and it works fine:

```
    If CBbf.Checked = True Then
        pgCommand.CommandText = "Select * FROM ""bf"" WHERE LOWER(""devname"") Like LOWER('" & TBname.Text & "%')"
        sda = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(pgCommand)
        sda.Fill(dtRecord)
    End If

    If CBhp.Checked = True Then
        pgCommand.CommandText = "Select * FROM ""hp"" WHERE LOWER(""devname"") Like LOWER('" & TBname.Text & "%')"
        sda = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(pgCommand)
        sda.Fill(dtRecord)
    End If
```

Now I would like to add a Column on each query, so that I know from which Query the output comes from.

e.g.:

[image]

So I would like to know how I can add the "from" column and fill the values according to the query I am doing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to your `select` that includes the table name:

```
Select bf.*, 'bf' as table_name FROM ""bf"" bf WHERE LOWER(""devname"") Like LOWER('" & TBname.Text & "%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider combining to a single query using UNION ALL.